# C++ String tokenisation from 3D .obj files

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I'm pretty new to C++ and was looking for a good way to pull the data out of this line.

A sample line that I might need to tokenise is

`f 11/65/11 16/70/16 17/69/17`

I have a tokenisation method that splits strings into a vector as delimited by a string which may be useful

`static void Tokenise(const string& str, vector<string>& tokens, const string& delimiters = " ")`

The only way I can think of doing it is to tokenise with " " as a delimiter, remove the first item from the resulting vector, then tokenise each part by itself.   Is there a good way to do this all in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the question is tagged as C++ but the absolutely easiest way to do this is with `scanf`

```
int indices[3][3];
sscanf(buffer, "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", &indices[0][0], &indices[0][1],...);
```

Comment: That's quite a nice way of doing it also.  I'll definitely keep in mind C functions in future, may even implement this.  Easily the most tidy solution, which is nice.

Comment: For .obj parsing this seems to be, for me at least, the solution that is easiest to read and write. You'll end up with around ~50 lines of code to parse the entire file format. Don't go the tokenizer-lexer-parser route; it's way to convoluted for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class parse_error : public std::exception {};

template< typename Target >
inline Target convert_to(const std::string& value)
{
  std::istringstream iss(value);
  Target target;
  iss >> target >> std::ws;
  if(!iss || !iss.eof()) throw parse_error();
  return target;
}

template< typename T >
inline T read_delimited_value(std::istream& is, char delim)
{
  std::string value;
  std::getline(is,value,delim);
  if(!is) throw parse_error();
  return convert_to<T>(value);
}

template< typename It >
inline void output(std::ostream& os, It begin, It end)
{
  while(begin!=end)
    os << *begin++ << ' ';
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> values;
  const std::string line = "f 11/65/11 16/70/16 17/69/17";

  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::string value;

  std::getline(iss,value,' ');
  if(value!="f" || !iss) throw parse_error();

  while(iss.good()) {
    values.push_back( read_delimited_value<int>(iss,'/') );
    values.push_back( read_delimited_value<int>(iss,'/') );
    values.push_back( read_delimited_value<int>(iss,' ') );
  }

  if(!iss.eof()) throw parse_error();

  output( std::cout, values.begin(), values.end() );
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would whoever down-voted this please tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm a bit fresh to programming to follow this well.  However I will be reading up on generic programming and templating to figure this out.  I'm under the impression this is a "correct" way to do it, however long it seems to be.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Ben: This only seems long until you have those three functions in your toolbox. Once you have, what remains is what's in `main()`, and that isn't all that long.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll probably be implementing this method, however I selected the other one simply because it answered my question more accurately

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/tokenizer/) and especially this:

```
// char_sep_example_1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str = ";;Hello|world||-foo--bar;yow;baz|";
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > 
    tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep("-;|");
  tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
  for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();
       tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
    std::cout << "<" << *tok_iter << "> ";
  std::cout << "\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check with my tutor if I can use Boost as part of this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the sample line you can use two delimiters ' ' and '/' and you will get all your numbers.

`static void Tokenise(const string& str, vector<string>& tokens, const string& delimiters = " /")`

Comment: Thanks, but my tokenise function doesn't work that way.  I'll be more clear in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove easily the first part until the first blank or the just after the f ( you can get the rest after the first blank with

```
istringstream iss( line );
std::getline( iss, restStr ,' ' )
```

Then you can use your tokenize function first on blank space and then on '/', or just use a set of std::getline and istringstreams in one loop.

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "f 1/2/3 4/4/2";

    std::istringstream issLine( s );

    std::string result;

    // remove the first "f"
    std::getline( issLine, result, ' ' );

    // parse blanks
    while( std::getline( issLine, result, ' ' ) )
    {
        std::istringstream issToken( result );
        std::string token;

        //parse content
        while( std::getline( issToken, token, '/' ))
        {
            std::cout << token << ',';
            // add your data in whatever you want
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```