# Optimal technique to parse a real-time char* data received from a buffer for text content in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, queue, gstreamer

I have created a live continuous mjpeg stream. A crude illustration is like this

```
....[image (jpeg)]->[text "content-length"]->[image (jpeg)]->[text "content-length"]->....
```

As you can see I receive data from gstreamer media pipe line which contains image and my own injected text
(Note: Although I am using Gstreamer, my question is only related to C++ principles.)

In order to parse this real-time data, I am trying to receive and push it into the queue. Subsequently I plan to parse the data for the word "content-length" after queue contains a certain number of packets.

My code looks like the following:

```
void clear( std::queue<char> &q )
{
   std::queue<char> empty;
   std::swap( q, empty );
}


static GstFlowReturn new_buffer (GstAppSink *app_sink, gpointer user_data)
{

  GstBuffer* buffer = gst_app_sink_pull_buffer(app_sink);

  //create queue
  std::queue<char> q;

  g_print("The input buffer contents are\n");

  gint i=0;
  for(i=0; buffer->data[i];i++)
  {  
      //g_print("\n%d",i);
      q.push(buffer->data[i]);
  }
  //g_print("\nsize of inbuf is %d\n",GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buffer)); 
  g_print("\n");  
  gst_buffer_unref(buffer);

  //#####################
  //parsing method here???
  //#####################

  clear(q);
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

I have used circular queues/ ring buffer in C/C++ before. Is that the best option? Or is the C++ STL queues would be more appropriate in this scenario like above?

Comment: why do you put `content-length` ***after*** content? instead of this you could just prefix each frame (image) by its size in binary form. why do you bother forcing to release queue memory by `clear()` function just before this will be done automatically on exit from your `new_buffer()`?

Comment: Apart from `"content-length"` I have `"timestamp"` too. I couldn't find a way to append that to "meta tags" of the stream. Hence I am squeezing all text data between the two image frames. I am actually using tee from gstreamer where my media pipeline forks. One end of the tee is where the stream goes to display. The other end of the stream is where I obtain buffer using appsink for parsing these text. Placing "content-length" before or after the jpeg image won't be a problem. But the jpeg itself has **header**`(0xFF, 0xD8)` and **footer**`(0xFF, 0xD9)` Hence I place data outside correct?

Comment: you can place any data before frame, just remember its format :) so it can be `content length` (4 bytes) and `timestamp` (4 bytes). when parsing your stream, you just takes content length and timestamp, then read the frame (you know its length)

Comment: So from what I understand: ...[ (`content-length`) text ] [ (`timestamp`) text ][ {`0xFF,0xD8`} (JPEG Frame) image {`0xFF,0xD9`} ] [ (`content-length`) text ] [ (`timestamp`) text ][ {`0xFF,0xD8`} (JPEG Frame) image {`0xFF,0xD9`} ] [ (`content-length`) text ] [ (`timestamp`) text ][ {`0xFF,0xD8`} (JPEG Frame) image {`0xFF,0xD9`} ]...Is it?

Comment: nope, [4 bytes = content-length][4 bytes = timestamp][jpeg image], no text at all, why do you need it if you know exactly where your data is?

Comment: ok I see So you are stating only "raw char Bytes" without the actual words `"content-length"` and `"timestamp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ringbuffer class

In header file declare

```
 //queue size
enum { rb_size = 5 };       // ---->element1 -> element2 -> .... -> elementN -> gap ->
                            // ^                                                     |
                            // |                                                     |  
                            // <--------------------<------------------<-------------V
typedef struct 
{
 char * data[rb_size];
 int head, tail;
} ring_buffer_struct; 

namespace myspace{
class ring_buffer{

    private:

    protected:          

    public: 
    //========= constructor ============
    ring_buffer()  
    {
    //If necessary initialization can happen here.

    }
    //========== destructor =============
    virtual ~ring_buffer()
    {

    }
    //===================================
    virtual void rb_start(ring_buffer_struct *b);
    virtual bool rb_empty(ring_buffer_struct const *b);
    virtual char *  rb_front(ring_buffer_struct const *b);
    virtual char *  rb_rear(ring_buffer_struct const *b);
    virtual void rb_pop_front(ring_buffer_struct *b);
    virtual ring_buffer_struct* rb_push_back(ring_buffer_struct *b);

}; //end of class
}
```

In cpp file

```
//start
void myspace::ring_buffer::rb_start(ring_buffer_struct *b)
{
b->head = 0; b->tail = 0;
}

//clear
bool myspace::ring_buffer::rb_empty(ring_buffer_struct const *b)
{
    return b->head == b->tail;
}

//front element
char *  myspace::ring_buffer::rb_front(ring_buffer_struct const *b)
{
return b->data[b->head]; //data gets popped
}

//rear element
    char *  myspace::ring_buffer::rb_rear(ring_buffer_struct const *b)
{
return b->data[b->tail]; //data gets pushed
}

//pop out front element
void myspace::ring_buffer::rb_pop_front(ring_buffer_struct *b)
{ 

    if(b->head < b->tail)  
{
      ++b->head; 
    }      
    if(b->head > b->tail)
{     
  b->head = 0;        
}

}

//push in rear element
ring_buffer_struct* myspace::ring_buffer::rb_push_back(ring_buffer_struct *b)
{
int new_tail = b->tail;

if (++new_tail >= rb_size)
{   //beginning of the queue
    new_tail = 0;      
}
if (new_tail != b->head)
{             
   //middle of the queue
    b->tail = new_tail;       
}
 if (new_tail <= b->head) 
     {
       b->tail = 0;           
     }

return b;
}
```

And to use in the main()

```
  ...

char element1[10] = "abcdefghi";
char element2[10] = "bcdefghij";
char element3[10] = "cdefghijk";

ring_buffer_struct rb;
myspace::ring_buffer q;
q.rb_empty(&rb); //make sure empty
q.rb_start(&rb); //start - initialize

    //initialize
    uint16_t i;
    for(i=0;i<rb_size;i++)
    {
     rb.data[rb.tail] = (char *)"000000000";
     q.rb_push_back(&rb);
    }

    rb.data[rb.tail] = element1;
    q.rb_push_back(&rb);
    q.rb_pop_front(&rb);         //now parse    


    rb.data[rb.tail] = element2;
    q.rb_push_back(&rb);
    q.rb_pop_front(&rb);    //now parse

      ...
```

For parsing: I looked at this post

[Simple string parsing with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880903/simple-string-parsing-with-c)

Answer (score -1):

Off topic suggestion:

When using the swap trick to clear out an STL container, don't call `std::swap` explicitly, as you may end up not getting a better-optimized version.  The better way is:

```
void clear( std::queue<char> &q )
{
   std::queue<char> empty;
   using std::swap;
   swap( q, empty );
}
```

This allows the compiler to choose a specialized version of `swap` that's optimized for the type of container you're using.  You could also try `q.swap(empty);`, but I'm not sure all STL implementations offer that.