# Extract integer from a string

Tags: c++, string, integer

I have string like "y.x-name', where y and x are number ranging from 0 to 100. From this string, what would be the best method to extract 'x' into an integer variable in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string by `.` and convert it to integer type directly. The second number in while loop is the one you want, see sample code:

```
template<typename T>
T stringToDecimal(const string& s)
{
    T t = T();
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> t;
    return t;
}

int func()
{     
    string s("100.3-name");

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    string line;

    while(std::getline(ss, line, '.'))
    {
         v.push_back(stringToDecimal<int>(line));
    }

    std::cout << v.back() << std::endl;

}
```

It will output: 3

Comment: @ billz: could you please explain ss >> t ?

Comment: `ss>>t` convert string(which can be `100` or `3-name`) to t, it only writes integer type and cut off unrelated string. just like atoi function. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Answer (score 0):

It seem that this thread has a problem similar to you, it might help ;)

[Simple string parsing with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880903/simple-string-parsing-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use two calls to [`unsigned long strtoul( const char *str, char **str_end, int base )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul), e.g:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char const * s = "1.99-name";
    char *endp;
    unsigned long l1 = strtoul(s,&endp,10);
    if (endp == s || *endp != '.') {
        cerr << "Bad parse" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    s = endp + 1;
    unsigned long l2 = strtoul(s,&endp,10);
    if (endp == s || *endp != '-') {
        cerr << "Bad parse" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "num 1 = " << l1 << "; num 2 = " << l2 << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), which utilizes streams like in billz' answer:
Pseudo code would look like this (indices might be wrong in that example):

```
std::string yxString = "56.74-name";
size_t xStart = yxString.find(".") + 1;
size_t xLength = yxString.find("-") - xStart;
int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>( yxString + xStart, xLength );
```

Parsing errors can be handled via exceptions that are thrown by lexical_cast.
For more flexible / powerful text matching I suggest [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).